# PIE.htc not working in IE8

Tags: css, css3pie

I've searched through the existing threads about PIE.htc not working in IE8 but couldn't find a good resolution -

I've tried applying it to every single element on my page that uses an IE8-incompatible CSS3 attribute and I can't get anything to happen. IE8 doesn't tell me that the path is wrong and PIE.htc sits in the same folder as the page which calls it. Here is a random css example from an element which pops up when the user hovers over a graphic:

CSS:

```
.info_bubble {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 8px 8px 16px 8px;
    background-color: white;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 1em;
    display: none;
    bottom: 2.5em;
    left: 3.5%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 0;
}
```

It is meant to have rounded edges but it still refuses to work in IE8.

Comment: Most problems are caused by incorrect file location. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676012/css-pie-not-working-with-correct-path-to-file

Comment: Triple-checked. It's in the same folder as the php file

Comment: is your server set to serve .htc?

Comment: I'm running the whole thing through WAMP. I'm using another htc polyfill (https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill) and it works correctly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured it out - Sort of.

It works if I use another version of PIE.htc. I have no idea why, but I guess for anyone else stuck in this situation, try a different version.

Edit: I was trying to use PIE 2.0 beta 1. I resolved the issue by downgrading to PIE 1.0.0.

Comment: Which version worked? Add that to your answer please.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this link](http://css3pie.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10), you should try to set `z-index` and `position:relative` to make the `border-radius` work IE8:

```
z-index: 0;
position: relative;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can't use a relative positioning unfortunately, although it still doesnt work even when I do

Answer (score 0):

The usual problem is that the path in the behavior rule is not correct.

As pointed out in the documentation http://css3pie.com/documentation/getting-started/ the path is relative to the HTML file not the CSS.

Comment: All of my css, php, and js files are in the same folder along with PIE.htc

Comment: There could also be .htaccess interference, you could use PIE.php

Comment: hmm... I am not entirely familiar with .htaccess. Any recommended reading?

Comment: I can't think of any other reasons for it not working.  Maybe you should just let IE8- users see square corners.  Even MS doesn't support IE8 anymore.  I stopped back in April when MS stopped.

Comment: I guess it isn't a big deal but it was one of quite a few features that wouldn't work. Regardless, I've solved the problem by using a different version of PIE.htc (who knows why)